# Multi-module IntelliJ project with maven - How to add dependencies from one module to another?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a `maven` project which has some maven modules inside.

My main module depends on the other modules, so when I compile the main module they should be compiled together.

The question is, how to add these modules as dependencies to the main module?

I know if I have a custom lib that I want to use with maven, let's say a `utilities project`, I have to compile the jar of the project, do a `mvn install:install-file` on it to install it on the local repository and then add it to the `pom.xml`.

Do I have to do this with all my modules and add the dependency to the `pom.xml` on my main module? Because if it should be done like this, there will be a lot of work to do when changing code on the other modules.

What is the best practice to use avoid the trouble of compiling/installing the modules to local repository?

Comment: Simply declaring as a dependency should work. At least it works with eclipse when resolve workspace artifacts is checked.

Comment: You mean adding the other modules as non-maven dependencies? Doing like this would make other users of the Project, after checking out from version control for example, have to resolve the dependencies between modules manually. If there are too many modules in the project, and internal dependencies between all the modules it would make life hard. There's no way to set the dependencies to other modules through pom.xml, so it can be shared through version control?

Comment: No, as a simple maven dependency. See: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-web.html

Comment: Manually installed Maven modules need to be `deploy`ed to some other remote location for them to be resolvable automatically by Maven. As @GáborBakos has mentioned, adding the other dependencies as simple Maven dependencies (using the `<dependency>` tags) will allow other users of the project to automatically resolve them when the project loads. Maven will handle all of it for you, assuming they are all remotely available for everyone. Take a look at setting up an internal repository for hosting your manually installed artifacts.

Comment: My local repository is shared through all the developers via dropbox, so everyone has the same local repository. Guess it will work, gonna try it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @MateusViccari it would be interesting to hear if it works out for you. I might suggest NOT sharing your local repository (that's what makes it local) and instead set up a remote repository (look at the `<distributionManagement>` tags) that's hosted over dropbox, so everyone gets a true remote and can keep their local to themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The question is, how to add these modules as dependencies to the main module?*

The same way you add any other dependency to your maven project. By adding group id, artifact id and version to `<dependency>` element

*Do I have to do this with all my modules and add the dependency to the pom.xml on my main module?*

If your main module **depends** on some module A then **only** the pom of the main module should contain dependency declaration towards module A. You do that for all the dependencies of your module.

I don't know what you mean by "a lot of work when changing the code on other modules". Maven has nothing to do with code changes, it just builds the projects whatever they look like at the given moment...

*What is the best practice to use avoid the trouble of compiling/installing the modules to local repository?*

Any project that you invoke `mvn install` on gets built and it's jar copied to local repository. That's all you need to do to get the jar into the repo. This will also put all the dependent jars, if available, into the local repo.

As for best practices for multi module projects:

If your parent project (the one that has modules inside) has `<modules>` section that lists the modules of your application, and modules are in subdirectories of your parent project, then you simply `mvn install` (or whatever you want to do) the parent project and that will cause all the modules to be built in order defined by declared dependencies between them. That means that if your main module has dependency on module A, then module A will be built before the main module. This way you can build and install all your modules with one command. On the other hand this approach makes more tight coupling between modules which is not desired in some cases, so it depends on your use case whether it is a good approach or not.